# Debug issue with ESP-IDF master version 5.3

Tags: debugging, esp32, esp-idf, openocd, espressif-idf

I am using **ESP-IDF** with **Eclipse**.

After updating master version to **5.3** *debugging is going to failed*.

I am using ESP32-C6 vboard.
while using debug mode using *ESP_IDF GDB OpenOCD Debugging* i'm getting some issues that is listed below

Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Error: no watchpoint at address 0x40825740 found
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted
**Error executing event gdb-attach on target esp32c6:**
C:\Users\user-id.espressif\tools\openocd-esp32\v0.12.0-esp32-20230921\openocd-esp32\share\openocd\scripts/target/esp_common.cfg:9: Error:
at file "C:\Users\user-id.espressif\tools\openocd-esp32\v0.12.0-esp32-20230921\openocd-esp32\share\openocd\scripts/target/esp_common.cfg", line 9
**Error: Target not halted
Error: auto_probe failed**
Error: Connect failed. Consider setting up a gdb-attach event for the target to prepare target for GDB connect, or use 'gdb_memory_map disable'.
**Error: attempted 'gdb' connection rejected**
shutdown command invoked

And same thing it was working with previous version 5.2.

Does anybody have any solution?

How should i make debugging works ?

Comment: Hi, you might have more luck when posting on the esp32.com forum.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the same issue answered here.
https://github.com/espressif/openocd-esp32/issues/315#issuecomment-1956404126

Please consider opening an issue in the Espressif OpenOCD GH repo so that you will most likely receive a faster response

Comment: Hello Erhan ,
Same thing i also tried after incresing that timing from 25 to 100. but than also debugging is not working for me .
The same things it was working for me with version 5.2.
So may be it is issue with version updation.